saving all data of real-time chart as a jpg windows forms
I have a real-time chart in my interface, but I'm having trouble finding a way to save all the data it displays. The chart.SaveImage() method only saves a screenshot of the current view of the chart, which is not sufficient for my needs. I need to capture and save all the data from the beginning to the end of the chart, including the parts that might get lost or scrolled out over time. How can I achieve this?
